# ubuntu 22.4 close mssql express 16.0.4085.2-1 by force

Tags: server, 22.04, mssql

Ubuntu version:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    mleUbuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

MSSQL version:
ii  mssql-server    16.0.4085.2-1   amd64 Microsoft SQL Server Relational Database Engine

Problem:
Can not connect to mssql server and use it from Windows Sertver 2012 R2 with this error:

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Seems a conflict between OpenSSL library.
Tried to install libssl1.0.0-dbg_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.20_i386.deb
but it is not installed due to public key unavailable.
No other solution found.
Need help